Custom error handler pipe operator function for RxJS
My goal is to create a new custom RxJS pipe operator which can handle every input like this
constructor(private errorHandler: ErrorHandlerService) {
  const voidStream$ = of() as Observable<void>;
  const stringStream$ = of('');
  const objectStream$ = of({ id: 1, value: 'some value' });

  voidStream$.pipe(handleError(this.errorHandler, () => of(undefined)));
  stringStream$.pipe(
    handleError(this.errorHandler, () => {
      // do some more stuff

      return of('');
    })
  );
  objectStream$.pipe(handleError(this.errorHandler, () => of(undefined)));
}

The main issue is how to deal with changing the return type.
export function handleError<T>(
  errorHandler: ErrorHandlerService,
  innerFunction: (error: any) => Observable<T>,
): OperatorFunction<T, T> {
  return (source: Observable<T>): Observable<T> => {
    return source.pipe(
      catchError((error) => {
        errorHandler.handleError(error);

        return innerFunction(error);
      })
    );
  };
}

Here is a Stackblitz you can play with.

I just applied the same typing of catchError and it started working fine. We also need to pass a second argument caught to the callback.
import {
  catchError,
  Observable,
  OperatorFunction,
  ObservableInput,
  ObservedValueOf,
} from 'rxjs';
import { ErrorHandlerService } from './error-handler.service';
// export function catchError<T, O extends ObservableInput<any>>(
//   selector: (err: any, caught: Observable<T>) => O
// ): OperatorFunction<T, T | ObservedValueOf<O>>;
export function handleError<T, O extends ObservableInput<any>>(
  errorHandler: ErrorHandlerService,
  customFunction: (err: any, caught: Observable<T>) => O,
  showNotification: boolean = true
): OperatorFunction<T, T | ObservedValueOf<O>> {
  return (source: Observable<T>): Observable<T> => {
    return source.pipe(
      catchError((error, caught) => {
        errorHandler.handleError(error);

        return customFunction(error, caught);
      })
    );
  };
}

Typescript:
import 'zone.js';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandlerService } from './error-handler.service';
import { Observable, of, throwError, map, tap, catchError } from 'rxjs';
import { handleError } from './handleError.function';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `<h1>Custom catchError() operator</h1>
  <p>Just an example to play with</p>`,
})
export class App {
  constructor(private errorHandler: ErrorHandlerService) {
    const voidStream$ = of().pipe(
      tap(() => {
        throw throwError('response');
      })
    ) as Observable<void>;
    const stringStream$ = of('').pipe(
      tap(() => {
        throw throwError('response');
      })
    );
    const objectStream$ = of({ id: 1, value: 'some value' }).pipe(
      tap(() => {
        throw throwError('response');
      })
    );

    voidStream$
      .pipe(handleError(this.errorHandler, () => of(undefined)))
      .subscribe(console.log);
    stringStream$
      .pipe(
        handleError(this.errorHandler, () => {
          // do some more stuff
          console.log('handling');
          return of('');
        })
      )
      .subscribe(console.log);
    objectStream$
      .pipe(handleError(this.errorHandler, () => of(undefined)))
      .subscribe(console.log);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo
